# Sharing Tor network via ad-hoc

Tags: windows-7, tor, ad-hoc-network

I'm using Tor for accessing sites that have been blocked by my ISP, which works great.

I use the same laptop with Windows 7 and wireless ad-hoc network to provide Internet access to other devices in
direct connection.

How can I make my ad-hoc network use Tor by default?

Answer (score 0):

If the other devices are smartphones, you can use [Orbot](https://guardianproject.info/apps/orbot/) to divert Web traffic via Tor 
for all or some applications on your phone.

Orbot is for the basic TOR functionality and [Orweb](https://guardianproject.info/apps/orweb/) is the web browser that uses Orbot.

Otherwise, you will need to set up on your computer software such as the 
[Advanced Onion Router](http://advtor.sourceforge.net/) (which I never used) and try to route traffic through Tor.
The [Virtual Router](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/) might also be a possibility.

Comment: So, the question is: **how** to route traffic through Tor and share it through wi-fi after that. Assume, that we know how to setup TOR on PC and how to share internet through wi-fi. We don't understand how to share specifically TORified connection via wi-fi

Comment: In theory, Orbot and Orweb take care of everything, so all you need is an Internet connection. I think this is just the opposite of what you are imagining - to let the devices connect through the unprotected ad-hoc Internet and let them connect to Tor on their own. Otherwise, the other (and more complex) option is to setup a virtual router that will connect to Tor and create a virtual wifi network for the devices. The Advanced Onion Router might help here if it does wifi, or if not then maybe Virtual Router. I never needed to use such software, so cannot help with the details.

Comment: Note also that even if the Advanced Onion Router or Virtual Router do not support wifi, you may still be able to bridge their network with your existing ad-hoc one into in effect one network.

Comment: @janot: Maybe you do not know that now there is a dedicated Stack Exchange site for Tor. There you can find for example the following question about redirecting all traffic into the Tor network which is closely related to the question above: [Running a virtual machine (VM) that can only connect through Tor](http://tor.stackexchange.com/q/330/114)

Comment: @pabouk I didn't know about that site. I'll try to ask there, thanks.

Comment: janot: Have you tried using a virtual router with the ad-hoc network? @pabouk: Your link is for Linux.